# PHP coding troubles

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, radio-button

I'm trying to learn how to use HTML, PHP, and MYSQL and trying to make a voting website using all three languages. Both MY HTML and MYSQL codes are fine and working, but I can't get my PHP code to work. I believe the problem is the fact I'm using radio buttons and not text input for the candidate's but I have no idea how to convert the data.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
      <title>U.S Election 2016</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>U.S Election 2016 - Voting Page</h1>

  <form action="insert_vote.php" method="post">
    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>Voter ID</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="VoterID" maxlength="13" size="13" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Candidate :</td>
       <td>
    <input type="radio" name="Candidate" value="Hillary Clinton" checked> 
        Hillary Clinton<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Candidate" value="Donald Trump" checked> 
        Donald Trump<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Candidate" value="Gary Johnson" checked> 
        Gary Johnson<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Candidate" value="Jill Stein" checked> 
        Jill Stein<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Candidate" value="None" checked> 
        Undecided/None of the Above<br>
    </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Cast Vote" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code:

```
    <html>
<head>
  <title>U.S Election 2016</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>U.S Election 2016 - Voting Page</h1>
<?php
  // create short variable names
  $VoterID=$_POST['VoterID'];
  $Candidate=$_POST['Candidate'];

  if (!$VoterID || !$Candidate) {
     echo "You have not entered all the required details.<br />"
          ."Please go back and try again.";
     exit;
  }

  if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $VoterID = intval($VoterID);
    $Candidate = addslashes($Candidate);
  }

  @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'Voting2016', 'Voting123', 'voting');

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     Echo "Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.";
     exit;
  }

  $query = "insert into voters values
            ('".$VoterID."', '".$Candidate."')";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  if ($result) {
      echo  $db->affected_rows." Vote has been cast and stored into database.";
  } else {
      Echo "An error has occurred.  Your vote was not added.";
  }

  $db->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Every time I submit the form it ask me if I want to download the PHP file:

[image]

Comment: Why does every radio button have `checked` in their input?

Comment: Could you be any less vague as to what your perceived problem is? How did you conclude it's the radio input? Where's the debugging output? Tried PDO/bound parameters instead of misguided SQL escaping yet? How about less error display suppression? Also isn't it kinda late for that particular script?

Comment: You haven't provided much information, but if I had to guess, you might be running into issues based on the "name" attribute on your radio buttons.  Instead of naming them "Candidate", try "Candidate[]".  Also, in PHP, you should be doing if(!empty($VoterID) || !empty($Candidate)).  if(!$VoterID) would only work as expected if $VoterID is a boolean.

Comment: the problem is every time i submit the form it ask me if i want to download php file rather than executing and sending the info to mysql. and to answer Mario last question "Also isn't it kinda late for that particular script?" this is for my database class and my professor assigned it so tell him that

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your PHP interpreter is not running. If it tells you to download a PHP file, it's probably because nothing interprets it. Look at WAMP (LAMP on Linux) to get it up and running correctly.

Edit: Looking at the code, it seems like you are new to programming. I suggest you look at some programming concepts, such as [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). You need to separate data, logic and presentation, else it will be a chaos, and chaos creates bugs. PHP allows you to do some nasty things, and starting with this language without knowing much about programming could give you some bad habits, so watch out :)